# Disable warning when using large datatables in R markdown

Tags: r, datatable, r-markdown, dt

I am using `DT::datatable` in a Rmarkdown file to output a table with 58302 rows and 6 columns. Based on what I have read, I cannot use server side processing in Rmarkdown, so I have to use the default client side to render the data table. I am getting the following warning which shows up in the markdown html output:

```
Warning in instance$preRenderHook(instance): It seems your data is too
big for client-side DataTables. You may consider server-side processing:
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html
```

How do I disable it?

Comment: You can set the option `warning=FALSE` in the chunk.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent can you move this to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the options of the R chunk, set `warning=FALSE`:

````
```{r mytable, warning=FALSE}
......
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the accepted answer did not work for me. However, setting an option *did* work to suppress the warning:

```r
options(DT.warn.size=FALSE)
```